# How can I changed tomcat app server to version 8 with jdk 1.7 and spring 3.0.4?

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

My project used tomcat 7 ,jdk 1.6 and spring 3.0.4. I changed tomcat version to 8, jdk to 1.7. It works perfectly in Luna IDE with tomcat installer.(Of course I changed servlet.jar to javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar because of an error)

My project is running perfectly with the tomcat8 (binary version) for windows, but the war file is not running with tomcat 8 (linux binary version) at linux server and its error is:

> Jun 14, 2015 5:32:47 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext
>   listenerStart SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to
>   listener instance of class utils.SysParams
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException:
>   Configuration problem: Failed to import bean definitions from relative
>   location [hibernate-beans.xml]   Offending resource: ServletContext
>   resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException:
>   Unexpected exception parsing XML document from ServletContext resource
>   [/WEB-INF/hibernate-beans.xml]; nested exception is
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.springframework.beans.MutablePropertyValues.add(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)Lorg/springframework/beans/MutablePropertyValues;

Comment: Do both the Windows and Linux environment have the same Spring jars on the classpath? Looks like it's loading a wrong version of the MutablePropertyValues class.

Comment: yes, I used same jars for both..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a Spring 3.0 method which should work in your case as it works on localhost. I guess your linux tomcat has pre-3.0 Spring versions somewhere in classpath- which could be from this project or legacy project. On linux tomcat check your classpath, search for spring 2* jars and try deleting work/temp folders..

Comment: only spring jar file with the version <3 that used is spring-ldap-1.3.0.RELEASE-all.jar

Comment: Have you checked all tomcat location server/lib or common/lib etc? Run unix search for all *jar files and check for curlprit. Its definitely a class path issue which can creep up in different ways.

Comment: there was spring.jar in lib. I removed that and that's work perfectly now. Many thanks for your help and suggestions..